# merge one column to the left and remaining columns to the right into one single data frame using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory

I would like to concatenate one column that I converted into a dataframe called ytrainSet with the remaining columns from xtrainSet of the data set. My input file is called  InputData.txt and you can access my full input under this link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_G61x0N-l70oPJOrNJ9NZ1nEGex06wWQ/view?usp=sharing

```
gold,Program,MethodType,CallersT,CallersN,CallersU,CallersCallersT,CallersCallersN,CallersCallersU,CalleesT,CalleesN,CalleesU,CalleesCalleesT,CalleesCalleesN,CalleesCalleesU,CompleteCallersCallees,classGold
T,chess,Inner,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,High,-1,-1,-1,Low,1,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,0,Trace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,0,NoTrace,
N,chess,Inner,-1,Low,-1,-1,Low,-1,-1,Medium,Medium,-1,High,High,0,NoTrace,
```

My full data is available under the following link:

Here is the code I am using to process this data:

```
    import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

SeparateProjectLearning=False


WeakenedCompleteCallersCallees=False
arr = [9, 54, 30, 88, 91, 76, 43, 27, 21, 18]
index=arr[0]
def main():
    X_train={}
    X_test={}
    y_train={}
    y_test={}
    dataset = pd.read_csv( 'InputData.txt', sep= ',', index_col=False) 
    #dataset = pd.read_csv( 'InputData.txt', sep= ',', index_col=False) 

    #convert T into 1 and N into 0
    dataset=dataset.drop(columns=['Program'], axis=1)
    dataset['gold'] = dataset['gold'].astype('category').cat.codes
    #dataset['Program'] = dataset['Program'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['classGold'] = dataset['classGold'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['MethodType'] = dataset['MethodType'].astype('category').cat.codes
    
    dataset['CallersT'] = dataset['CallersT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersN'] = dataset['CallersN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersU'] = dataset['CallersU'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersCallersT'] = dataset['CallersCallersT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersCallersN'] = dataset['CallersCallersN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CallersCallersU'] = dataset['CallersCallersU'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesT'] = dataset['CalleesT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesN'] = dataset['CalleesN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesU'] = dataset['CalleesU'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesCalleesT'] = dataset['CalleesCalleesT'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesCalleesN'] = dataset['CalleesCalleesN'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['CalleesCalleesU'] = dataset['CalleesCalleesU'].astype('category').cat.codes

    
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)


    #print(dataset.head())
    row_count, column_count = dataset.shape
 
   
    X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:column_count].values
    y = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values
        
    print(dataset.head())
    CompleteSet=dataset.loc[dataset['CompleteCallersCallees'] == 1] 
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=len(CompleteSet)/(len(X)*2), random_state=index) 
        
    ytrainSet = pd.DataFrame(np.array(y_train).T)
    xtrainSet = pd.DataFrame(np.array(X_train))
    print('====!!!!!!!\n',ytrainSet.head())
    print('====!!!!!!!\n',xtrainSet.head())
    #THE LINE WHERE EVERYTHING CRASHES IS RIGHT BELOW:
    remainingSet = pd.merge(ytrainSet, xtrainSet)
      
    print('====\n',remainingSet.head())

    
if __name__=="__main__": 
    main()
```

All the lines of the program ending with `.cat.codes` aim at converting string values into numeric values from 0,1,2,etc. Then, my problem arises when I am trying to concatenate the column ytrainSet with the columns forming xtrainSet. I am trying to concatenate the following column

```
====!!!!!!! First column //DATA FRAME 1
    0
0  0
1  0
2  0
3  0
4  0
```

with the remaining columns that I am pasting below

```
 ====!!!!!!! remaining columns //DATA FRAME 2
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
0   0   0   0   2   0   3   2   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   3   0   0   3   0   2   3   0   0   2   0   1
2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
3   0   0   2   0   0   3   0   0   0   2   0   0   2   0   0
4   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   3   0   0
```

In other words I would like my result `remaining Set` to be made of the first column all the way to the left concatenated with the 15 columns that I just pasted above. The resulting data frame should be made of 16 columns with the first column of DATAFRAME1 being the leftmost column and then followed by all the lcolumns contained in DATAFRAME2.

My program crashes in the line `remainingSet = pd.merge(ytrainSet, xtrainSet)` and I get the following traceback to the error that I am pasting below:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
runfile('C:/Users/mouna/ownCloud/Mouna Hammoudi/dumps/Python/StackOverflowTest.py', wdir='C:/Users/mouna/ownCloud/Mouna Hammoudi/dumps/Python')

File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/mouna/ownCloud/Mouna Hammoudi/dumps/Python/StackOverflowTest.py", line 64, in 
main()

File "C:/Users/mouna/ownCloud/Mouna Hammoudi/dumps/Python/StackOverflowTest.py", line 58, in main
remainingSet = pd.merge(ytrainSet, xtrainSet)

File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 62, in merge
return op.get_result()

File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 568, in get_result
join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()

File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 777, in _get_join_info
right_indexer) = self._get_join_indexers()

File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 756, in _get_join_indexers
how=self.how)

File "C:\Users\mouna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1148, in _get_join_indexers
return join_func(lkey, rkey, count, **kwargs)

File "pandas_libs\join.pyx", line 54, in pandas._libs.join.inner_join

MemoryError

Comment: Give a reproducible and sample data. Don't dump just everything. It is hard to decipher anything here.

Comment: @Mainland I gave reproducible code just copy and paste the code I provided you with in your Python editor and run it and you will get the same error I got. I even provided the entire input file I am using in a public link